# How unsporting is the answer-delete-edit-undelete strategy?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, undelete, fastest-gun

Sometimes, while answering questions on SO, I've noticed myself falling into a pattern that goes something like this:

1. Post quick answer that cursorily addresses the problem at hand (let us assume for argument's sake it is an accurate if incomplete answer, although this is by no means always the case). Quickly delete this answer.
2. Do some research/revision and come up with an example that compiles/runs; edit this in
3. Undelete my answer and profit from the fact that my answer is the oldest one there

Lately I've been feeling like this is a form of gaming the system, and it should be somehow disincentivized or curtailed.

My question is whether any one else does this, or feels strongly about those that do.

My opinion is that the practice isn't really non-constructive, it just lets me hog all the rep and isn't really fair.

Comment: Nobody is even gonna notice or care that it's the oldest answer. The only thing this matters at all for is the Enlightened badge.

Comment: @Mysticial Very frequently identical answers that are newer receive fewer votes than the first ones. I suppose this has partly to do with the human factor of giving credit where they believe it is due, and partly because answers are automatically sorted in chronological order.

Comment: THis is basically FGITW, I am not sure what purpose the deleting serves. Opnions are varied on the dickishness of FGITW strategies. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: @Asad No they are not sorted by chronological order. They are by votes. If there are ties, they are randomized. However, you can override the order with the one of the other tabs.

Comment: @KateGregory The delete basically makes the answer inaccessible to review, so even if it is a poor answer I get no downvotes and can fix it at my leisure.

Comment: It must also be said that sometimes you genuinely realise a major flaw in your answer and you do this to avoid down-votes before you manage to fix it.

Comment: @Mysticial Didn't know that. I assumed in the absence of any votes questions were sorted by order.

Comment: @Mysticial disturbingly enough many people *do* seem to care about posting the oldest answer. They shouldn't, but that doesn't stop everyone.

Comment: Just a note: your having deleted and undeleted it also [becomes a **permanent** part of the post's revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13322827/revisions) (example linked). It's not like people can't see what you did.

Comment: I consider this "not-cool" practice very similar as when a user "Post something incomplete very quickly, then edit the post with other answer's informations, finally post a code example 5-10 mins later." This user has a really high rep > 70k (for instance), then "edited" mark won't show, so it looks like he filled the whole thing in like a minute after the question has been made. Pretty nasty IMO.

Comment: @animuson Even if you do it within the grace period?

Comment: @animuson: not if it's within the grace period. (I did that once today, realizing I missed part of the Q. There's no revision history on the post.)

Comment: @Matt: A deletion shows up in the history no matter when it is done. The grace period is *only* for editing.

Comment: @animuson: I posted an answer today, deleted it ~30s after posting realizing it had an incorrect part, edited and undeleted. Took less than 2 min. total. There is no revision history on the post. Try it yourself here if you want.

Comment: @Mysticial Have a look here for an example of earlier answer being preferred here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13334887/1726343. This conveniently popped up as the discussion was underway.

Comment: @Mat: I'd say that's a bug then. If you look at the example I linked, both of the deletions occurred within the grace period, but the edit occurred after the grace period.

Comment: @Asad 1 vs. 2 votes is hardly "preferred". 5 vs. 10 is something more significant.

Comment: @animuson: you're right. It is recorded. But it's not visible on the post itself.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13332966/635608 / http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13332966/revisions

Comment: @Mysticial There were hardly any votes to go around, probabbly because the question sort of fizzled out. A 5 to 10 split is the same ratio as a 1 to 2 split, although in this case I was pointing to the fact that the OP took the time to consider who posted first when accepting an answer (btw I do not think this is unreasonable at all)

Comment: @Mat: That is simply because *events* such as deleting, converting to CW, locking, closing, etc do not count as "edits" to the post and do not add an "edited x time ago" link to the post.

Comment: @animuson Well no one is going to dig around in the revision history for an answer on an impulse, so it might as well be invisible to the public.

Comment: So it's "It's not like people can't see what you did" if they dig hard enough.

Comment: @Mat: Well, if he's editing it outside the grace period then the link will be there anyways. And editing is a key part of the process we're discussing here.

Comment: "2... edit this in, 3. Undelete my answer" I don't think you can do it in that order, I have done this and I remember the fear of getting DV while I was doing the edit, so I wrote my answer in my text editor then quickly did the changes with copy-paste

Comment: @ajax333221 You can, try it.

Comment: @Asad interesting, [it works](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/148736/revisions), but I am very sure this was not possible couple of months ago

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a valid, reasonable, case where that kind of thing might happen:

- Post an answer with untested (but likely correct) code quickly because you think "hey, totally easy"
- Either notice that your answer is incorrect or not detailed enough to be helpful or receive a comment telling you about that => delete it.
- Improve it and undelete it when done.

No matter why you do so - it will **not** let you "hog all the rep". The answers are sorted by score and in case of equal score in random order. The only advantage of having the first answer is having the chance of getting the 10+-first-answer-accepted silver badge for it.